# What game is being promoted in this Xbox Games Pass advertisement

Tags: game-identification

I’ve seen this game on my Xbox home page for about two weeks now but I can’t immediately identify what it is. Selecting the advertisement takes me to a page where I’m prompted to purchase Xbox Game Pass Ultimate, but doesn’t provide information on what game was used in the promotion.

Here is the advertisement in question:[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is [DayZ Standalone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DayZ_(video_game)). Here is a reference image

[image: DayZ image]

Source: [Steam News Hub for DayZ](https://store.steampowered.com/newshub/app/221100)